# Get unique Object from a Stream if present

Tags: java, java-stream

Starting with a bean class `MyBean` with a single relevant propterty:

```
@Data
class MyBean {
    private String myProperty;
}
```

Now I have got a set of these beans `Set<MyBean> mySet` usually with 0, 1, or 2 elements.

The question is: How do I retrieve `myProperty` from this set if it is equal for all elements, or else null. Preferably in a single line with effort O(n).

I found several examples to determine the boolean if all properties are equal. But I want to know the corresponding property.

Is there something smarter than this?

```
String uniqueProperty = mySet.stream().map(MyBean::getMyProperty).distinct().count() == 1 
    ? mySet.stream().map(MyBean::getMyProperty).findAny().orElse(null) 
    : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your version is already `O(n)`.

It's possible to do this with a one-liner (although yours is too depending on how you write it).

```
String uniqueProperty = mySet.stream()
    .map(MyBean::getMyProperty)
    .map(Optional::ofNullable)
    .reduce((a, b) -> a.equals(b) ? a : Optional.empty())  // Note: equals compares 2 Optionals here
    .get()  // unwraps first Optional layer
    .orElse(null);  // unwraps second layer
```

The only case this doesn't work for is when all property values are `null`.  You cannot distinguish the set `(null, null)` from `(null, "A")` for example, they both return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a single iteration without the use of streams looks much better for such a use case :

```
Iterator<MyBean> iterator = mySet.iterator();
String uniqueProperty = iterator.next().getMyProperty();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    if (!iterator.next().getMyProperty().equals(uniqueProperty)) {
        uniqueProperty = null; // some default value possibly
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the `findAny()` first and check `mySet` again with `allMatch()` to require all items to match the first one in a `filter()`:

```
String uniqueProperty = mySet.stream().findAny().map(MyBean::getMyProperty)
        .filter(s -> mySet.stream().map(MyBean::getMyProperty).allMatch(s::equals))
        .orElse(null);
```

The advantage of this is, that `allMatch()` will only evaluate all elements if necessary ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-)).